# How to get single row from database and set the values of that row to textview's

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-activity

Am new in android app development. I tried to find the solution of this problem but nothing was useful at last i am asking this question.

1) I am making profile in app but i want to show only name and email in that with the help of textviews. Data is inserted without error but i don't know how to get it and set on textview. Here is my code of database

```
public void User(String email,String name,SQLiteDatabase db){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUser.EMAIL,email);
    contentValues.put(UserContract.NewUser.NAME,name);
    db.insert(UserContract.NewUser.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    Log.e("Database Operations", "User Added...");
}

public Cursor getMyProfile() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ UserContract.NewUser.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Using "User" data is inserted but I am getting error in "getMyProfile".Here is the profile code by which i want to set data to textview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
    MyName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MyName);
    MyEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyEmail);

    Cursor cursor = userHelper.getMyProfile();
    while (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        MyName.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        MyEmail.setText(cursor.getString(1));

    }
```

2) Can anyone tell me how to save an image in database, Means i want to add profile picture but i do not know about that how to do that any suggestion.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What error are you getting on `getMyProfile`?

Comment: this `while (cursor.moveToFirst()){` is probably an infinite loop. you should put moveToFirst in front of while and use moveToNext in while. Or since you probably have only one record do not use while loop. Just use moveToFirst and fill the data.

Comment: when i switched to profile intent app show message "app is not responding" , am also not sure about code                                                            Is Code is correct or need some changes

Comment: Like i saied: `while (curosr.moveToFirst())` in infinite loop. It never exits. because the loop keeps getting the fisrt child in cursor. Your code should be `Cursor cursor = userHelper.getMyProfile(); cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        MyName.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        MyEmail.setText(cursor.getString(1));

    }` or just simply `Cursor cursor = userHelper.getMyProfile();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
        MyName.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        MyEmail.setText(cursor.getString(1));`

Comment: getting an error "**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MyProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException**"

Comment: can you check if how many row are in your table using `cursor.getCount();` Comment the rest of it out.

Comment: I just found the problem. It's the while loop. It skippes the first record and goes to the second one. Just use `Cursor cursor = userHelper.getMyProfile(); cursor.moveToFirst(); MyName.setText(cursor.getString(0)); MyEmail.setText(cursor.getString(1));`

Comment: Nomeaning25 can you send me code in which textview get data from database

Comment: cant seem to find PM. Will edit my answer

Comment: did u check database is syntex is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Fix your function to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);
    MyName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MyName);
    MyEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyEmail);

    Cursor cursor = userHelper.getMyProfile();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    MyName.setText(cursor.getString(0));
    MyEmail.setText(cursor.getString(1));
}
```

in one of my applications I use `for` loop to fill my activity:

```
public void fillGrid(Cursor c){
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.players_table);
        tl.removeAllViews();
        for(c.moveToFirst(); c.getPosition() < c.getCount(); c.moveToNext()){
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(c.getString(1));
            tr.addView(tv);
            tl.addView(tr);
        }

        c.close();
    }
```

To select the data i do the following:

```
    ...
        SQLiteDatabase db = tpdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        String[] projection = {
                Player.PlayerEntry._ID,
                Player.PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME
        };

        Cursor c = db.query(
                Player.PlayerEntry.TABLE_NAME,  //table name
                projection,                     //which columns
                null,                           //where clause columns
                null,                           //where clause values
                null,                           //group columns
                null,                           //filter by row groups
                null                            //order
        );

        fillGrid(c);
    ...
```

2) You could save the bytes of an image to a BLOB column. I think something like iunputStream could work